# Select unique values for one column

Tags: postgresql, duplication

There is a table with different sets a(1,2), b(2,3,4) and etc.

```
-- table1 --
set_name | value
a        | 1
a        | 2
b        | 2
b        | 3
b        | 4
c        | 3
c        | 5
...      | ...
```

How to get a table containing name of set with values which is unique for all table? Result should be like this:

```
-- table2 --
set_name | value
a        | 1
b        | 4
c        | 5
...      | ...
```

Since value 2 is in set a and set b, it's excluded; since value 3 is in sets b and c, it's excluded....

In other words, I want to see the rows where the `value` is listed for *one and only one* `set_name`.

Comment: What if it shows up two times in the same set?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> create table test(set_name text, value int);
> insert into test values
> ('a', 1),('a', 2),('b', 2),('b', 3),
> ('b', 4),('c', 3),('c', 5);
> ```

You can use a Window function and a CTE (you can move the CTE part to a subquery), to get the desired result.

> ```
> ;with x as
> (
>     select set_name, value, 
>            count(value) over (partition by value) cnt
>     from   test
> )
> select set_name, value
> from   x
> where  cnt = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> set_name | value
> :------- | ----:
> a        |     1
> b        |     4
> c        |     5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=18a3bf42ac3dcac9e0bf4f79f0fa804b)*

Answer (score 2):

If the table has only these 2 columns - and no more - then you could use a simpler query (and I assume that the table has a primary key):

```
select min(set_name) as set_name, value 
from table1
group by value
having min(set_name) = max(set_name) 
order by set_name;
```

Comment: Why a primary key is required?

Comment: @McNets because otherwise there might be two identical rows, say with `('b', 4)`. On one hand I wouldn't know what the expected output would be in this case and on the other hand a table without a primary or an unique key is not really a table (at least in relational theory ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   a.set_name,
   b.value
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
      value,
          COUNT(1) AS val_count 
       FROM table1
       GROUP BY value
       HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
    ) b ON a.value = b.value
ORDER BY a.set_name
```

To break down the logic of the script:

1. I get first the list of values in `value` column where there is only 1 instance of it.
2. Then joined it on the original table with the join clause of the `value` column.

This will surely work for a simple table like in your example. If you have a very large data, lets try to optimize this query.

Answer (score 1):

A [`NOT EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-anti-join should be intuitive:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   test
   WHERE  value = t.value
   AND    set_name <> t.set_name
   );
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fa5c7f2818322ef1762310ed5e1b07f2)* <sub>(building on McNets fiddle)</sub>

This returns whole rows (or any arbitrary selection of columns).
Assuming both columns to be defined `NOT NULL` - or you have to declare how you intend to deal with NULL values (consider equal or not?).

An index on `(value, set_name)` (columns in this order) helps performance with big tables *a lot*.

Related:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)